# Finding relation between coefficients in a limit

Tags: limits, roots, quadratics

I was practicing questions and got stuck at this. There is no solution provided in the book. What I guessed is that we will be using the properties of discriminant of a quadratic equation and draw the graphs and choose an $x_0$, but I do not know how to actually proceed with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

> Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of $a x^2+b x+c=0,$ where
>   $1<\alpha<\beta .$
>
> Then $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \frac{\left|ax^2+bx+c\right|}{a x^2+b x+c}=1$ then which of
>   the following statements is incorrect
>
> **(a)** $a>0$ and $x_0<1$
>
> **(b)** $a>0$ and $x_0<\beta$
>
> **(c)** $a<0$ and $\alpha<x_0<\beta$
>
> **(d)** $a<0$ and $x_0<1$

Comment: thanks i got it!

Comment: No, determinant doesn't has to be negative. (>ლ) if it was negative $\alpha$ and $\beta$ wouldn't be greater than 1. This question can be understood by a graph easily.

Answer (score 1):

https://undergroundmathematics.org/quadratics/r5138/images/q5138.png
See this graph for a>0 (The labeling of the graph is incorrect, and I can't find another one)
Those points are the roots. first one is $\alpha$ and second one is $\beta$. Both are greater than 1

$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \frac{\left|ax^2+bx+c\right|}{a x^2+b x+c}=1$$

Forget the modulus, without the modulus, the limit is always 1, provided $x_0≠ \alpha,\beta$. But since modulus is there, the limit can be -1 too.

HINT:
If $a>0$ and $x_0>\beta$, both numerator and denominator will be positive.
now you can check all the options, I suppose.